Updating two parameters separately in the same argument (ECHARTS)
I need to update two arguments inside series.data, the name and the value. The problem is that I can't separate this update in a formal way. I even manage to do it, for example, by creating another echarts leaving the rest of the chart invisible and leaving only one argument in this new series.
What I need is to update the name and value without them interfering with each other. For example:
(1) If I change the name, the value can't be updated
(2) If I change the value, the name cannot be updated
This is because they have different events (one is change and the other is click on different HTML tags).
Code:


// initialize echarts
let echartsGaugeDropUse = echarts.init(document.getElementById('gaugeChart'));

// create dataset
function getDataset() {
  let name1 = document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText;
  let value1 = Number(document.getElementById('valueInput').value);

  return {
    'source': [
      ['name', name1],
      ['value', value1]
    ]
  };
}

// init config
function update1() {
  let option = {
    title: [{
      text: "BEER",
      top: '30%',
      left: 'center'
    }],
    series: [{
      type: 'gauge',
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      progress: {
        show: true,
        overlap: true,
        roundCap: true,
        clip: false,
        width: 20
      }
    }]
  };

  echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption(option);
}

update1();

// update funcion 
function updateGaugeData() {

  let newName = document.getElementById('changeInput').value;
  document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText = newName;

  let dataset = getDataset();

  let gaugeData = [{
    name: dataset.source[0][1],
    value: dataset.source[1][1],
    title: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    itemStyle: {
      emphasis: {
        shadowBlur: 10,
        shadowColor: 'green',
        borderColor: 'lime'
      }
    }
  }];

  echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption({
    series: [{
      data: gaugeData
    }]
  });
}

// value only
document.getElementById('valueInput').addEventListener('change', function() {
  updateGaugeData();
});

// name only
document.getElementById('changeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  updateGaugeData();
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ECharts Gauge Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!--INITIAL NAME-->
  <span id='nameInput' style='display: none;'>SPAN</span>

  <!--NEW NAME-->
  <input id='changeInput' type='text'>

  <!--BUTTON TO CHANGE NAME-->
  <button id='changeButton'>Change name</button>

  <!--VALUE-->
  <input id='valueInput' type='range' min='0' max='100' value='50'>

  <!--PLOT-->
  <div id="gaugeChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>

</html>



As it is, the change in one interferes with the other. I know this because the same update function is being used in the events. I would like to know if there is a formal way to change the two parameters separately, instead of having to update both simultaneously.
I tried it too:


    // initialize echarts
    let echartsGaugeDropUse = echarts.init(document.getElementById('gaugeChart'));
    
    // create dataset
    function getDataset() {
      let name1 = document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText;
      let value1 = Number(document.getElementById('valueInput').value);
    
      return {
        'source': [
          ['name', name1],
          ['value', value1]
        ]
      };
    }
    
    // init config
    function update1() {
      let option = {
        title: [{
          text: "BEER",
          top: '30%',
          left: 'center'
        }],
        series: [{
          type: 'gauge',
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          progress: {
            show: true,
            overlap: true,
            roundCap: true,
            clip: false,
            width: 20
          }
        }]
      };
    
      echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption(option);
    }
    
    update1();
    
    // update funcion 
    // update function 
    function updateGaugeData(eventType) {
      // Check the event type
      if (eventType === 'name') {
        let newName = document.getElementById('changeInput').value;
        document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText = newName;
      } else if (eventType === 'value') {
        let dataset = getDataset();
    
        let gaugeData = [{
          name: dataset.source[0][1],
          value: dataset.source[1][1],
          title: {
            color: 'red'
          },
          itemStyle: {
            emphasis: {
              shadowBlur: 10,
              shadowColor: 'green',
              borderColor: 'lime'
            }
          }
        }];
    
        echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption({
          series: [{
            data: gaugeData
          }]
        });
      }
    }
    
    // value only
    document.getElementById('valueInput').addEventListener('change', function() {
      updateGaugeData('value');
    });
    
    // name only
    document.getElementById('changeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
      updateGaugeData('name');
    }); 



But it doesn't work.

I dont quite understand what the problem is. Could you elaborate or provide a minimal reproducable example in the echarts editor?

@MatthiasMertens Within series, there is the date argument. Within data, there is value and name. I need to make sure that updating one does not affect the other. For example, I'm going to translate the text of name, but when I change the language, the value can't be updated. And vice versa, when I change the value, the name can't update. See that I put two different events there, one for name and the other for value. Updating one can't affect the other. But I'd like to keep the same structure as the chart, i.e. avoid any workarounds.

It seems like echarts doesnt allow to partially update the data attribute. So I dont see any other possibility than always providing both, name and value.

I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want to avoid the animation of the pointer from zero when you change the name (and possibly to be able to initialize the name without an initialization of the value/pointer), since you can't partially update a data point, as @Matthias Mertens stated in the comments, you're left with the option to separate the value (+pointer and progress) in a data point and the name in another:


// initialize echarts
const echartsGaugeDropUse = echarts.init(document.getElementById('gaugeChart'));

// init config
function update1() {
    let option = {
        title: [{
            text: "BEER",
            top: '30%',
            left: 'center'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'gauge',
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            progress: {
                show: true,
                overlap: true,
                roundCap: true,
                clip: false,
                width: 20
            }
        }]
    };

    echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption(option);
}

update1();

// update funcion
function updateGaugeData(eventType) {
    const data = echartsGaugeDropUse.getOption().series[0].data ?? [];
    if (eventType === 'name') {
        let newName = document.getElementById('changeInput').value;
        document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText = newName;
        if(data.length <= 1){
            data.push({ // initialization of name data item
                detail:{
                    show: false
                },
                progress: {
                    show: false
                },
                itemStyle:{
                    opacity: 0
                },

                name: newName,
                value: 0,
                title: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            data[1].name = newName;
        }
    }
    else{ // if (eventType === 'value') {
        const newValue = Number(document.getElementById('valueInput').value);
        if(data.length <= 1){ // initialization of value data item
            data.unshift({});
        }
        data[0].value = newValue;
    }

    echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption({
        series: [{
            data
        }]
    });
}

// value only
document.getElementById('valueInput').addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateGaugeData('value');
});

// name only
document.getElementById('changeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    updateGaugeData('name');
});
<!--INITIAL NAME-->
<span id='nameInput' style='display: none;'>SPAN</span>

<!--NEW NAME-->
<input id='changeInput' type='text'>

<!--BUTTON TO CHANGE NAME-->
<button id='changeButton'>Change name</button>

<!--VALUE-->
<input id='valueInput' type='range' min='0' max='100' value='50'>

<!--PLOT-->
<div id="gaugeChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js"></script>



Possibly excessive, but with the advantage of simplicity, you can even separate the value and name into two different series:


// initialize echarts
const echartsGaugeDropUse = echarts.init(document.getElementById('gaugeChart'));

// init config
function update1() {
    let option = {
        title: [{
            text: "BEER",
            top: '30%',
            left: 'center'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'gauge',
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            progress: {
                show: true,
                overlap: true,
                roundCap: true,
                clip: false,
                width: 20
            }
        }]
    };

    echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption(option);
}

update1();

// update funcion
function updateGaugeData(eventType) {
    const opts = echartsGaugeDropUse.getOption();
    const series = opts.series;
    if (eventType === 'name') {
        let newName = document.getElementById('changeInput').value;
        document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText = newName;
        if(series.length === 1){
            series.push({
                ...series[0],
                anchor: {
                    show: false
                },
                detail:{
                    show: false
                },
                progress: {
                    show: false
                },
                pointer: {
                    show: false
                },
                data: [{
                    name: newName,
                    value: 0,
                    title: {
                        color: 'red'
                    }
                }]
            });
        }
        else{
            series[1].data[0].name = newName;
        }
    }
    else{
        const newValue = Number(document.getElementById('valueInput').value);

        if(!series[0].data || series[0].data.length === 0){
            series[0].data = [{}];
        }
        series[0].data[0].value = newValue;
    }

    echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption({
        series: series
    });
}

// value only
document.getElementById('valueInput').addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateGaugeData();
});

// name only
document.getElementById('changeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    updateGaugeData('name');
});
<span id='nameInput' style='display: none;'>SPAN</span>

<!--NEW NAME-->
<input id='changeInput' type='text'>

<!--BUTTON TO CHANGE NAME-->
<button id='changeButton'>Change name</button>

<!--VALUE-->
<input id='valueInput' type='range' min='0' max='100' value='50'>

<!--PLOT-->
<div id="gaugeChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js"></script>




It's a little unclear what exactly your desired outcome is, but I think your problem mostly stems from the way you've structured your stateful/mutable code. This becomes a lot simpler if you separately define your state and how to modify that state, and your renderer, which should be a pure function (only sort of pure in this case because of how echarts works) that takes your (updated) state and displays your chart. Separating out the state handling, and parameterizing the animation based on which event we're handling gives what you want I think.


// initialize echarts
let echartsGaugeDropUse = echarts.init(document.getElementById('gaugeChart'));

// create dataset
const createStateManager = (initialState = [['name', ''], ['value', 0]]) => {
  let state = initialState;
  return {
    getState: () => state,
    updateState: (mapper) => {
      state = mapper(state);
      return state;
    }
  };
}

stateManager = createStateManager()

// init config
function update1() {
  let option = {
    title: [{
      text: "BEER",
      top: '30%',
      left: 'center'
    }],
    series: [{
      type: 'gauge',
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      progress: {
        show: true,
        overlap: true,
        roundCap: true,
        clip: false,
        width: 20
      }
    }]
  };

  echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption(option);
}

update1();

// update funcion 
function updateGaugeData(state, animate=true) {
  echartsGaugeDropUse.setOption({
    animation: animate,
    series: {
      data: [{
        name: state.source[0][1],
        value: state.source[1][1],
        title: {
          color: 'red'
        },
        itemStyle: {
          emphasis: {
            shadowBlur: 10,
            shadowColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'lime'
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  });
}

// value only
document.getElementById('valueInput').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const newValue = Number(document.getElementById('valueInput').value);
  const newState = stateManager.updateState(oldState => ({
    source: [oldState.source[0], ['value', newValue]]
  }))
  updateGaugeData(newState);
});

// name only
document.getElementById('changeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const newName = document.getElementById('changeInput').value;
  document.getElementById('changeInput').value = '';
  document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText = newName;
  const newState = stateManager.updateState(oldState => ({
    source: [['name', newName], oldState.source[1]]
  }))
  updateGaugeData(newState, false);
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let name1 = document.getElementById('nameInput').innerText;
  let value1 = Number(document.getElementById('valueInput').value);
  const initializedState = stateManager.updateState(oldState => ({
    source: [['name', name1], ['value', value1]]
  }))
  updateGaugeData(initializedState); //initialize the chart
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ECharts Gauge Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!--INITIAL NAME-->
  <span id='nameInput' style='display: none;'>SPAN</span>

  <!--NEW NAME-->
  <input id='changeInput' type='text'>

  <!--BUTTON TO CHANGE NAME-->
  <button id='changeButton'>Change name</button>

  <!--VALUE-->
  <input id='valueInput' type='range' min='0' max='100' value='50'>

  <!--PLOT-->
  <div id="gaugeChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>

</html>




This post contains a valuable approach, but its explanation is misleading (it has nothing to do with how the OP "structured their stateful/mutable code") and the whole functional programming talk and code is obfuscating the real valuable idea, which is: disable animation when updating the title, so it appears the gauge pointer didn't move. Here's a minimal change version of OP's code incorporating that idea. However, this doesn't allow the initialization of the title without the initialization of the pointer, but it's not clear that is a required feature.

The state modification changes are key to ensuring only one element is updated at a time. In the original code the updateGaugeData function contains the DOM queries which update the state directly. This means if you input into the text box a name change, do not submit, but then adjust the gauge, the new name would be applied without clicking the button. Additionally, simply reducing the surface area of a function makes it easier to reason about. This has absolutely nothing to do with functional vs imperative design.

That's right. I hadn't thought about the case when the input is changed but the button is not pressed.
